# Moving the screen in windows - Low level programming

Tags: windows, screen, low-level

OK, this is going to sound strange. Is it possible to programmatically move the screen? For example, by moving the screen down, you will not see the windows start button anymore and the top part of the screen will be shown as black. It's a bit hard to describe. It's like manipulating the way the desktop and the whole environment is shown by windows. What language should I use for such thing. Could it be done with C++.

Many thanks

Comment: Oh, it's a complicated project. Let's just suppose you have a very very big touch screen and you can not reach the top by hand and if you can't go up there then why don't you bring that part of the screen down!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This greatly depends on the Windows version in question.

- Everything up to WinXP: Impossible to do using only standard API. Doing this requires hacking into the graphics drivers
- Windows XP and later allow for flexible assignment of screen space to the desktop, thanks to the support of expanding the desktop over multiple graphics cards. But please don't ask me about the specific API calls for this. Your best bet would be looking in the MSDN graphics driver development section.